# I dont understand probability functions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

My question reads: Given that the probability function of X is as follows:

$$
{\rm f}\left(x\right) \equiv {\sqrt{\,x + 9\,} \over 10}\,,\qquad x = -8, -5, 0, 7.
$$

(a) Find the mean of $X$.

(b) Find the expected value of $\sqrt{\,Y\,}$ where
$Y = {\rm g}\left(x\right)$ and ${\rm g}\left(x\right)= x + 9$.

So, I know because I was told that the mean of $X$ is equal to $1$, but how am I supposed to arrive at that conclusion?.

What specific steps do I take to find the mean? and I'm totally clueless about part (b.).

In your explanation please use baby steps, because I have never felt so crushingly unintelligent in my mathematical life. -Tim

Comment: The formula is a fancy way of saying that the probability that $X=-8$ is $\frac{\sqrt{-8+9}}{10}$, which is $\frac{1}{10}$. Similarly, the probability that $X=-5$ is $\frac{2}{10}$, the probability that it is $0$ is $\frac{3}{10}$, and the probability that $X=7$ is $\frac{4}{10}$. Now I assume you know how to find the mean.

Comment: oh holy tits ya I add (-8) to 2(-5) to 3(0) to 4(7) and divide by 10, 10/10 = 1! but my god i never would have got there on my own

Comment: @felixmarin based on Andre's comment, I think $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+9}}{10}$.

Comment: @undergrad Yes. It's true. But that was the way the OP wrote it. I guess there was a typo in the OP writing. I'll changed but I'll add a comment for the OP to be aware of that.

Comment: Following @AndréNicolas and $\tt\mbox{@undergrad}$ comments I took the factor $\large 10$ out of the root. I'll appreciate the OP will check this change and shows his agreement (or not) with this. Thanks to both ${\tt\mbox{@AndreNicolas}}$ and ${\tt\mbox{@undergrad}}$.

Comment: @undergrad I just make a change. See my comment in the OP question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**(a)**

A probability function gives the probability that a discrete random variable is equal to a value.

Here: $\operatorname{P}(X=x)=f(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{x+9}}{10}, \quad \forall x\in \Omega: \Omega=\{-8,-5,0,7\}$

The (arithmetric) mean of a random variable is the sum of the product of all possible values and their probabilities.  It's the expected value of the variable.

$\overline{X} $ $= \operatorname{E}[X] = \sum\limits_{x\in\Omega} x\cdot\operatorname{P}(X=x) \\ = \sum\limits_{x\in\Omega} x\cdot f(x) \\ = \dfrac{\mathbf{-8}\sqrt{\mathbf{-8}+9}}{10}+\dfrac{\mathbf{-5}\sqrt{\mathbf{-5}+9}}{10}+\dfrac{\mathbf{0}\sqrt{\mathbf{0}+9}}{10}+\dfrac{\mathbf{7}\sqrt{\mathbf{7}+9}}{10} \\ = \ldots$

---

**(b)**

The expected value of a function of a variable is the sum of the product of the image of all possible the values and their probabilities.

$\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{fun}(X)] = \sum\limits_{x\in\Omega} \operatorname{fun}(x)\cdot \operatorname{P}(X=x)$

Now since $Y=g(X)$ and $g(x)=x+9$ then:

$\therefore \operatorname{E}[\sqrt Y]$ $= \operatorname{E}[\sqrt{X+9}] \\ = \sum\limits_{x\in\Omega} \sqrt{x+9}\cdot f(x) \\ = \sum\limits_{x\in\Omega} \dfrac{|x+9|}{10} \\ = \ldots$